# How to extract jmeter response value

Tags: jmeter

I did read few responses but my regular expression extractor is not working.

- Mine is a simple case where this is my response

> token.id=AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcz4cOT2RrremxWJmM3llZmPl6k0bP_r5D4.*AAJTSQACMDUAAlNLABQtNDI1OTg4NzgxODg5MDM1ODU2NQACUzEAAjI3*

- I am trying to grab the value using this expression

  token.id="(.*?)"

which is not saving the value into the variable i assigned. My next request when trying to use the value fails since its not grabbing it. 
Can someone let me know what exactly is missing. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your regular expression:

1. You need to escape dot between "token" and "id" with backslash as it is a special character. See [Literal Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) article for more information.
2. You don't need the quotations marks as your response doesn't contain them (does it?)

So your regular expression needs to be amended as `token\.id=(.*)` (however I would rather go for something like `token\.id=(\w.+)`

You can use View Results Tree listener in "RegExp Tester" mode to test your regular expressions directly against response without having to re-run the request.

[image: RegExp Tester]

See [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) JMeter documentation chapter and [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for extended information on the above approaches.